# Dropping token animations on a connect four board

Tags: javascript, css, animation, html-table

I've just finished working on a fully functioning Connect Four board, but I want to integrate animations for when the tokens are falling into the board. I'm looking for a simple Javascript/CSS solution, no jQuery or anything like that. It'd be optimal to have the element itself fall into the desired slot, but if that's not possible, I understand.

My code is structured with 7 different functions (one for each row of the table they are organized in). Within each one, it checks what the lowest open hole is, so that it knows where to drop it.

HTML:

```
    <table>
      <tr id="droprow">
        <td><button onclick = "drop1()" class = "droplocation" id="Z1">+</button></td>
        <td><button onclick = "drop2()" class = "droplocation" id="Z2">+</button></td>
        <td><button onclick = "drop3()" class = "droplocation" id="Z3">+</button></td>
        <td><button onclick = "drop4()" class = "droplocation" id="Z4">+</button></td>
        <td><button onclick = "drop5()" class = "droplocation" id="Z5">+</button></td>
        <td><button onclick = "drop6()" class = "droplocation" id="Z6">+</button></td>
        <td><button onclick = "drop7()" class = "droplocation" id="Z7">+</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A1"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A2"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A3"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A4"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A5"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A6"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="A7"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B1"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B2"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B3"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B4"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B5"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B6"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="B7"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C1"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C2"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C3"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C4"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C5"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C6"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="C7"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D1"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D2"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D3"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D4"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D5"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D6"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="D7"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E1"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E2"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E3"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E4"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E5"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E6"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="E7"></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F1"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F2"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F3"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F4"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F5"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F6"></button></td>
        <td><button class = "hole" id="F7"></button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

(The droprow row is the row of buttons that you click to drop a token in that column.)

JavaScript (for row one, all other rows follow this exact same format, but the id's are changed):

```
function drop1() {
  if(turn == "red" && gameisover == false) {
    if(f1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("F1").style.backgroundColor = "#f44256";
      f1isempty = false;
      f1isred = true;
      checkForRedWin();
    } else if(e1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("E1").style.backgroundColor = "#f44256";
      e1isempty = false;
      e1isred = true;
      checkForRedWin();
    } else if(d1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("D1").style.backgroundColor = "#f44256";
      d1isempty = false;
      d1isred = true;
      checkForRedWin();
    } else if(c1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("C1").style.backgroundColor = "#f44256";
      c1isempty = false;
      c1isred = true;
      checkForRedWin();
    } else if(b1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("B1").style.backgroundColor = "#f44256";
      b1isempty = false;
      b1isred = true;
      checkForRedWin();
    } else if(a1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("A1").style.backgroundColor = "#f44256";
      a1isempty = false;
      a1isred = true;
      checkForRedWin();
      checkForRedWin();
    } else {
      alert("Looks like that column is filled up! Let's try another one, shall we?");
    }
  } else if(turn == "blue" && gameisover == false) {
    if(f1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("F1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
      f1isempty = false;
      f1isblue = true;
      checkForBlueWin();
    } else if(e1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("E1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
      e1isempty = false;
      e1isblue = true;
      checkForBlueWin();
    } else if(d1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("D1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
      d1isempty = false;
      d1isblue = true;
      checkForBlueWin();
    } else if(c1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("C1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
      c1isempty = false;
      c1isblue = true;
      checkForBlueWin();
    } else if(b1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("B1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
      b1isempty = false;
      b1isblue = true;
      checkForBlueWin();
    } else if(a1isempty == true){
      document.getElementById("A1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
      a1isempty = false;
      a1isblue = true;
      checkForBlueWin();
    } else {
      alert("Looks like that column is filled up! Let's try another one, shall we?");
    }
  }
}
```

It works just fine, but there's something about the way it just kind of pops into existence that annoys me.

(Yes, I know it would've been smarter to just use a single function with parameters, but I didn't think of that at the time, so. That doesn't really matter though; it's already done.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to add a class with a CSS animation when you set the background color.

```
.fall {
    animation-name: fall-animation;
    animation-duration: 500ms;
}

@keyframes fall-animation {
    from {
        transform: translateY(-500px);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}
```

And then when you set the background color, also add this class:

```
document.getElementById("A1").style.backgroundColor = "#4183f4";
document.getElementById("A1").classList.add('fall');
```

This is kinda hacky in that they'll all fall from 500px above where they rest, but you could do some math and figure out where each row's tokens should start.

Here's a fiddle of that idea in action: https://jsfiddle.net/7mvL0240/1/

Comment: It works great! Annoying bug, though - when you drop it, the background color of the area changes to whatever is behind it, so the grey background of the hole turns the turquoise color of the background. Will make a fiddle for it in a bit.

Comment: Actually, on second thought, there's no need for a fiddle, I can deal with a slight coloring error. Again, thank you, it looks great.